# Referencing external dependencies in GGTS by convention

Tags: grails, dependency-management

How do I reference a dependency by convention within my project build path?  Allow me to elaborate...

I'm using the Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS 3.0).  I'm referencing the dependency as such in my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'tgt:jaxb-utils:1.0'
}
```

The referenced jar file is successfully pulled down from the Artifactory repo - I can find the jar file on my local file system in the Ivy cache.  When I run any grails targets (`grails compile`, `grails run-app`, `grails run-tests`), it works fine  - meaning my code that imports the classes from the jar has no problems.  When I run `grails war`, the referenced jar file is packed into the constructed war.

However, and here is the crux of this post - the project build path does not reference this jar file by default or convention, so my java or groovy code that imports the classes from the jar file reports a `unable to resolve class ...` error.

One solution is to simply add the jar file to the lib folder and update the build path accordingly, or modify the build path to reference the jar file in the Ivy cache folder.  However, I'd have to do this for any/all dependencies pulled down in this way.  Any jars in the lib folder will get saved to the team source code repository, and that seems like wasted space since the grails commands work fine with just the dependency reference in BuildConfig.groovy.

Am I just being too idealistic (ie - difficult) here, or is there a better way to clean up the `unable to resolve class ...` errors in my IDE without having to manually add the dependent jar files to my lib folder and update my build path?  Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse / STS / GGTS : If you have Grails plugin installed, you can do the following :

Right click on your project -> Grails Tools -> Refresh dependencies (or shortcut "Alt+G, R")

Comment: Perfect - I just learned a new trick with the tooling.  Thank you!