# Grails GGTS - Refresh dependencies failed

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-management, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I get build errors in the GGTS Groovy error when I import a class from an external jar.

I've added a jar dependency to my Grails project using `BuildConfig.groovy` that is installed to my local maven repo:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
  repositories {
    ...
    mavenLocal()
  }
...
}

dependencies {
  runtime(group: 'groupId', name: 'nameId', version: 'versionId')
}
```

When I import a class from that jar, I get the error in the GGTS Groovy editor `Groovy: unable to resolve class...` I can run `grail compile` and `grails run-app` from either the command line or GGTS. So clearly Grails has no problem finding the jar and referencing it from my code.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371474/referencing-external-dependencies-in-ggts-by-convention) suggested that the user run 'Refresh dependencies (or shortcut "Alt+G, R")' but that results in an error dialog.

```
Refresh dependecies failed
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Opening up the Error Log View shows the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.PluginDescriptorParser.handleSimpleNode(PluginDescriptorParser.java:216)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.PluginDescriptorParser.parse(PluginDescriptorParser.java:100)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.GrailsPluginParser.parse(GrailsPluginParser.java:39)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PerProjectPluginCache.parseData(PerProjectPluginCache.java:110)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PerProjectPluginCache.initializePluginData(PerProjectPluginCache.java:81)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PerProjectPluginCache.refreshDependencyCache(PerProjectPluginCache.java:103)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommandUtils$1.run(GrailsCommandUtils.java:392)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2327)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommandUtils.refreshDependencies(GrailsCommandUtils.java:372)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.runInWorkspace(GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.java:89)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I am using:

```
Grails 1.3.7
GGTS 3.4.0.RELEASE-e4.3.1-linux-gtk-x86_64
```

How do I fix this error and be able to edit my code in GGTS without errors?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in GGTS where the project was getting compiled fine from command prompt (grails run-app) but GGTS was showing problem as "Unable to resolve class GrailsTestCase". I checked Dependency management (project right click -> Grails Tools) and it was enabled. I just disabled it and enabled it again. This resolved the issue in my case. Could be some problem with IDE.